# Will a Quartz Scheduler delete the file once the job executed?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, jobs, job-scheduling

I have a scheduled Job in Quartz Scheduler , In the job i have marked a file to deleteOnExit.

```
File file = new File(downloadedFile);
file.deleteOnExit();
```

Will this file get deleted ever, since my scheduler is deployed ? I mean the scheduler will load the job and everytime when it needs to trigger the Job it will create a new instance of the job. but the process will never end , it will keep on running , so will deleteOnExit method work there ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the deleteOnExit() javadoc:

"Requests that the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname be deleted when the virtual machine terminates."

So the file will be deleted only when your Java VM terminates, not when the job completes.

Comment: Does each quartz job spin up it's own VM, or is it a continuing instance?

Comment: @Mike - It'll be a continuing instance.@Adon, yes correct.

Comment: That's what I assumed, so deleteOnExit() would not take effect and the file would not be deleted.